# Median absolute deviation from numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I work with a 4D numpy array where I compute statistics `mean, meadin, std` along the 3rd dimension of the array like so:

```
import numpy as np
input_shape = (1, 10, 4)
n_sample =20
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample,)+input_shape)
X.shape
(20, 1, 10, 4)
```

Then I compute the `mean, med,` and `std-dev` this way:

```
sta_fuc = (np.mean, np.median, np.std)
stat = np.concatenate([func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in sta_fuc], axis=2)
```

So that:

```
stat.shape
(20, 1, 3, 4)
```

represent the values of the `mean, median` and `std` along that dimension.

But then I would like to add the value of the column's mean absolute deviation `mad` so that the statistics is (`mean, median, std, mad`), but it appears `numpy` doesn't provide a function for that. How do I add `mad`to my statistics?

**EDIT**

As far the first answer, using the defined function, i.e.:

```
def mad(arr, axis=None, keepdims=True):
    median = np.median(arr, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    mad = np.median(np.abs(arr-median, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims),
                    axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims)
    return mad
```

Then adding `mad` to the statistics, which generate an error, like so:

```
sta_fuc = (np.mean, np.median, np.std, mad)
stat = np.concatenate([func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in sta_fuc], axis=2)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-22-dab51665f952> in <module>()
      1 sta_fuc = (np.mean, np.median, np.std, mad)
----> 2 stat = np.concatenate([func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in sta_fuc], axis=2)

1 frames

<ipython-input-21-84d735c8c516> in mad(arr, axis, keepdims)
      1 def mad(arr, axis=None, keepdims=True):
      2     median = np.median(arr, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
----> 3     mad = np.median(np.abs(arr-median, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims),
      4                     axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims)
      5     return mad

TypeError: 'axis' is an invalid keyword to ufunc 'absolute'
```

**EDIT-2**

Using the `scipy` function suggested by @Jussi also generates error as below:
from scipy.stats import median_absolute_deviation as mad

```
sta_fuc = (np.mean, np.median, np.std, mad)
stat = np.concatenate([func(X, axis=2, keepdims=True) for func in sta_fuc], axis=2)

TypeError: median_absolute_deviation() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keepdims'
```

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. You ask for the MEAN absolute deviation in the title, but then the question is about the MEDIAN absolute deviation. These are very much not the same thing.

Comment: thank you, this has been corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a built-in solution using numpy. But you can implement it based on numpy functions fairly easily, using `mad = median(abs(a - median(a)))`.

```
def mad(arr, axis=None, keepdims=True):
    median = np.median(arr, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    mad = np.median(np.abs(arr-median),axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims)
    return mad
```

Comment: thank you, using this function generates 'axis' is an invalid keyword to ufunc 'absolute' error as in the question edit.

Comment: should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I've seen MAD referring to median absolute deviation. If that's what you want, it's available in the SciPy library as `scipy.stats.median_absolute_deviation()`.

It's also pretty easy to write a suitable function yourself.

Edit: here's a MAD function that takes a `keepdims` argument:

```
def mad(data, axis=None, scale=1.4826, keepdims=False):
    """Median absolute deviation (MAD).
    
    Defined as the median absolute deviation from the median of the data. A
    robust alternative to stddev. Results should be identical to
    scipy.stats.median_absolute_deviation(), which does not take a keepdims
    argument.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : array_like
        The data.
    scale : float, optional
        Scaling of the result. By default, it is scaled to give a consistent
        estimate of the standard deviation of values from a normal
        distribution.
    axis : numpy axis spec, optional
        Axis or axes along which to compute MAD.
    keepdims : bool, optional
        If this is set to True, the axes which are reduced are left in the
        result as dimensions with size one.

    Returns
    -------
    ndarray
        The MAD.
    """
    # keep dims here so that broadcasting works
    med = np.median(data, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    abs_devs = np.abs(data - med)
    return scale * np.median(abs_devs, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims)
```

Comment: @super_ask I added a mad() function that takes keepdims.